# Exception Handling with dll

Tags: c#, exception, filenotfoundexception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

So, I have this Universal Windows Platform app that used to work perfectly fine at first on both mobile and computer but when I installed the latest Anniversary update and then tried running the same application it threw above app.

I have tried following methods to try and resolve this:
Updated all Nuget packages related to project
Made sure that file was referenced in Project.json and under References
Copied mscorlib.ni.dll file in bin manually 
Added that file in solution manually

Comment: You gotta provide us with some more information than that. What is the goal you are trying to achieve? What is causing you difficulty in getting there? What is the line of code that is giving you this error?

Comment: Looks like your actual problem is permissions. The FileNotFoundException is probably happening as a result of not being able to read (and/or write) the file location directory.

Comment: I don't know, everytime I run my application it throws this application.

I have made some checks on page loaded event where an API call is made

Comment: I could send you guys a link to my github repo if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Run visual studio as administrator. Exception should disappear.

Comment: I tried doing that after reading @Odrai's comment but that didn't help :/